# Flask-Restful ignores blueprint's url_prefix

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I want to use Flask blueprints to organize my Flask-Restful resources into separate url prefixes.  Regardless of what url prefix I set (during either blueprint creation or registration), everything gets mapped to the raw route paths.  How do I correctly use Restful with blueprints?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Building, '/<int:id>', endpoint='building')
api.add_resource(Jack, '/<int:id>', endpoint='jack')

building_api = Blueprint('building_api', __name__)
jack_api = Blueprint('jack_api', __name__)

app.register_blueprint(building_api, url_prefix='/buildings')
app.register_blueprint(jack_api, url_prefix='/jacks')
```

All [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/#registering-blueprints) I can find says that these should now be available at `/buildings/<int:id>` and `/jacks/<int:id>`, but both of those urls 404 and instead I can access the building one at `/<int:id>`.  Hard coding the path in `add_resource` fixes it, but defeats the point of `url_prefix`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [pass the blueprint](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intermediate-usage.html#use-with-blueprints) to the `Api` instance, not the app.

```
building_bp = Blueprint('buildings', __name__)
building_api = Api(building_bp)
building_api.add_resource(Building, '/<int:id>')
app.register_blueprint(building_bp, url_prefix='/buildings')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is zhe best way to do with blueprint:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp)

class TodoItem(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        return {'task': 'Say "Hello, World!"'}

api.add_resource(TodoItem, '/todos/<int:id>')
app.register_blueprint(api_bp)
```

you should send Blueprint'instance to Api

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why but I struggled using the `Blueprint` as mentioned in the answers.

But here's a **quick solution** I found while going through the [doc link](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#id1). Making use of the `prefix` parameter in `Api()` does the job.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app, prefix='/buildings')
```

Now, all your routes will be prefixed with `/buildings`. Just make sure you use `url_for('link')` in places where you might have simply used a `/link`.

One more strange thing I noticed is that atleast for me, it did not work until I renamed my routes to the same name as their class names. For example, `Class Home(Resource)` should have a route to `/home`. Using `/homeepage` or any other route for `Home Class` causes an error. Not sure if it is only me.